vlc player does not start on Ubuntu 24
After installing VLC player on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I cannot use it.
The following error appears:
user@lh:~$ vlc
Driver does not support the 0x4680 PCI ID.
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
VLC media player 3.0.20 Vetinari (revision 3.0.20-1-g2617de71b6)
[00005ce65b1d6a00] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [0 205)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


Did you try to uninstall vlc and install the version from the website? https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.de.html  Possible the problem is in the sources of Ubuntu, not vlc itself.

I tried the App Center and yes via your link sudo snapp install vlc.

Most likely, the problem is snap. Replacing with apt version may fix the issue. Duplicate of: VLC and other media players does not start! While running through CLI I got segmentation fault error!. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks, this post helped me:
VLC and other media players does not start! While running through CLI I got segmentation fault error!
sudo snap remove vlc
sudo apt install vlc

